# Grammar/Punctuation

Tags: grammar, terminology, punctuation

I often see people criticizing people's grammar and then pointing out punctuation mistakes. Surely grammar and punctuation are two separate things. Grammar is about using the correct word, tense, etc. not whether you missed a comma or used an apostrophe incorrectly.

Why is punctuation important in written English compared with grammar, and when should it be corrected?

Is grammar and punctuation the same thing or are they two different things?

Comment: Without appropriate punctuation, sentences can take on an altogether different meaning. e.g. *Let's eat, grandma* versus *Let's eat grandma*.

Comment: That's a *much* better example than mine!

Comment: You define grammar in a way that excludes punctuation, then you conclude that grammar and punctuation are separate.  This is just playing with words.

Comment: Yes, many people think that ‘grammar’ is more or less everything about a language that can be codified, which is not how it’s used in more technical contexts… but do you have an actual question here, or is this just a rant?

Comment: @Janus It's a reasonable question (even if implied), and users may wonder why their punctuation is sometimes commented on and at other times, not.

Comment: @Mick I think this question can be reopened if it is edited with a question.

Comment: What is grammar? What is punctuation? Is punctuation part of grammar? Why do linguists and kindergarten teachers differ in their answers to these questions? Can punctuation affect grammar? Can I use punctuation incorrectly speaking over the loudspeaker? Are people who use punctuation differently wrong? Why do people disagree about punctuation? How and when was punctuation invented? What about writing? Or speech? Or language? Can a sentence be a sentence even devoid of punctuation? Is capitalization punctuation or grammar? Why do people like to hurt other people's feelings by correcting them?

Comment: @tchrist You ask a lot of questions.

Answer (score 2):

The sense of *grammar* that is in everyday use is not the same sense that is used in linguistics. The non-scientific sense is more like "official orthography, prescribed syntax and prescribed morphology".

The entry at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammar) makes this distinction:

- "A system of rules and principles for speaking and writing a language."
- "(*uncountable*, *linguistics*) The study of the internal structure of words (morphology) and the use of words in the construction of phrases and sentences (syntax)."

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammar) makes a similar distinction, without including orthography:

- "the study of the classes of words, their inflections, and their functions and relations in the sentence"
- "a study of what is to be preferred and what avoided in inflection and syntax"

As does [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grammar), without enough detail to judge whether they consider proper writing to be part of the non-scientific sense of grammar:

- "*[mass noun]* The whole system and structure of a language or of languages in general, usually taken as consisting of syntax and morphology (including inflections) and sometimes also phonology and semantics."
- "A set of actual or presumed prescriptive notions about correct use of a language."

Comment: Agreed. But I think the split you note in the fist sentence is not so academic. It is very informal (almost to the extent of 'incorrect' by secondary school students to think of grammar as including orthography or punctuation).

Answer (score 1):

## it is really quite simple

punctuation is an artifact of orthography
       and
orthography is a form of technology

grammar is a part of language
       which is the tongue spoken
              by each of us

grammar comprises
       syntax
 and
      morphology

morphology is how individual words change their form depending on the job they are doing like
       MAN
becoming 
       MEN
and
       LIKE
becoming
       LIKING
or
       LIKED

syntax is how words fit together to create meaning through the ordered assembly of larger structures which allows us to assign completely different meanings to

MEN LIKE WOMEN
and
       MEN WOMEN LIKE

grammar exists in a blind illiterate speaker
       
for it is part of the spoken language
       the living language
              our brains
              have special hardware
       to process

punctuation
does
not

---

<sub>this grammatically correct posting not only explains the difference between matters grammatical and orthographical but also illustrates those differences by way of direct example</sub>

Comment: You are the very model of a modern major-general and I claim my $5.

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation can affect the meaning of sentences. Consider the oft-quoted:

- Eats shoots & leaves.
- Eats, shoots & leaves.

They have rather different meanings. The first indicates that something eats both shoots and leaves. The second indicates that someone eats, then fires a gun and walks away.

For this reason, correct grammar and appropriate punctuation often go hand in hand, and punctuation is then of interest to us. At other times, it is either a matter or personal preference or an issue to be resolved by appropriate style guides.

Legislators and lawyers do their utmost to remove as much punctuation from written English as they possibly can, so as to minimise the chances of poorly-judged punctuation making a nonsense of laws. They do not always succeed.

[Wikipedia: Eats, Shoots & Leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves)

Comment: Not really, it is the grammar that affects the meaning of those sentences, through their different syntaxes, and different stress patterns. Punctuation is just a way of encoding the spoken differences which is produced by the grammar.